# PDO: Is lastInsertId() a separate query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

If I have this code:

```
<?php
    $q = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (row) VALUES ('1')");
    $q->execute();

    $lastid = $sql->lastInsertId(); // is this a 2nd query?
?>
```

Would it run as two separate SQL queries?

If so, is there a way to do it in one?

Comment: Are you searching for **[transaciton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)**? It can make two separated SQL calls into one **atomic** call.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one query?

Comment: ^Because I would like to get the ID of the row I just inserted without querying the database twice

Comment: @supercoolville Why do you think `I would like to ... without querying ...`?

Comment: lol.....so no data is automatically returned when a row is successfully inserted?

Comment: @supercoolville exactly xD

Answer (score 3):

```
    $lastid = $sql->lastInsertId();
```

it works like a query because it will select from database the last inserted id.

as the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) said

> Returns the ID of the last inserted row, or the last value from a sequence object, depending on the underlying driver.

Answer (score 3):

No, in fact it doesn't run an SQL query.

Here's the line from ext/pdo_msyql/mysql_driver.c:

```
char *id = php_pdo_int64_to_str(mysql_insert_id(H->server) TSRMLS_CC);
```

This is a call to the MySQL API, [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-insert-id.html). This internally accesses the last insert id as a property, not by running SQL.